# SwiftUI: Unable to access Edit Mode within TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently have a view `HostView` that provides `HostSummaryView` and `EditHostSummaryView`, where the former responds to `editMode.wrappedValue? == .inactive`. `HostView` looks like this:

```
struct HostView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            EditButton()
        }
        
        if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
            HostSummary()
        } else {
            EditHostSummary()
        }
    }
}
```

I have a `RootView` that contains a `TabView`, which looks like this:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            View1()
                .onTapGesture { self.selectedTab = 0 }
                .tag(0)
            
            View2()
                .tag(1)
            
            HostView()
                .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried passing the `@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode` to `HostView`, but that did not fix the problem. The `EditButton` does not toggle `editMode` in the `HostView`. However, `HostView` works when I access it through a non-`TabView` view.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a previous question about this but it is known that some things don't work from within a `TabView` you have to push it down a `View`.

I think it is considered a bug.

```
struct EditableHost: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("View 1")
                .onTapGesture { self.selectedTab = 0 }
                .tag(0)
            
            Text("View 2")
                .tag(1)
            ParentHostView()
                .tabItem { Text("host") }
                .tag(2)
        }
        
    }
}
struct ParentHostView: View {
    @State var active: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(
                destination: HostView(),
                isActive: $active,
                label: {
                    Text("HOST")
                })
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
struct HostView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack {
                EditButton()
            }
            if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
                Text("HostSummary")
            } else {
                Text("EditHostSummary")
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same case(Xcode 13.3, iOS 15.4). You can customize an edit button and everything should be ok.

```
struct HostView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                if editMode != nil{
                    if editMode!.wrappedValue == .inactive{
                        editMode!.wrappedValue = .active
                    }else{
                        if editMode!.wrappedValue == .active{
                            editMode!.wrappedValue = .inactive
                        }
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true ? "Done" : "Edit")
            }
        }
        
        if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
            HostSummary()
        } else {
            EditHostSummary()
        }
    }
}
```